What restriction(s) is preventing my Add-Computer command from adding a computer to the domain
What restriction(s) is preventing my Add-Computer command from adding a computer to the domain ? :
PS C:\> Add-Computer -DomainName myDOMAIN.lan -Credential myDOMAIN\myUSER -OUPath "OU=Computers,DC=myDOMAIN,DC=lan"
Add-Computer : Computer 'myPC' failed to join domain 'myDOMAIN.lan' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with following error message: Account restrictions are
preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Computer -DomainName myDOMAIN.lan -Credential myDOMAIN\myUSER  -OUPath " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (myPC:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand

I see no LogonWorkstations restriction for this user :
PS C:\> Get-ADUser myUSER -Property LogonWorkstations | % LogonWorkstations
PS C:\> 

How can I list the restrictions of my user with Powershell ?
